# access error 3061 Too Few parameters expected 1

Tags: ms-access, vba

Help! i am having some trouble with my access codes on a database whereby it says that access error 3061 Too Few parameters expected 1. Problem highlighted was

```
Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

---

```
    Dim i As Date, n As Integer, oRS As DAO.Recordset, sSQL As String

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim BookedDate As Date
Dim FacilitiesID As String
Dim StartTime As Date

cboTime.RowSourceType = "Value List"
cboTime.RowSource = ""
If IsNull(Start) Then Exit Sub Else i = Start
If Me.NewRecord = True Then
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
End If
sSQL = "SELECT FacilitiesID, StartTime, BookedDate"
sSQL = sSQL & " FROM qrysubform"
sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE FacilitiesID= " & Me.FacilitiesID & _
                        " AND BookedDate=# " & Me.txtDate & "#"
Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Facilities ID is dimensioned as a string, though in your SQL statement it is referenced as a number.  If your form's FacilitiesID is in fact a string, you need to enclose it in quotes:

```
sSQL = "SELECT FacilitiesID, StartTime, BookedDate"
sSQL = sSQL & " FROM qrysubform"
sSQL = sSQL & " WHERE FacilitiesID= '" & Me.FacilitiesID & _
                        "' AND BookedDate=#" & Me.txtDate & "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

In such cases, insert a *debug* line and study the output:

```
Debug.Print sSQL
' Study output
Set oRS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSQL)
```

That said, this error is typically caused by a missing or misspelled field name.